# How to delete Microsoft Edge recovery files

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, microsoft-edge

I found out that when I closing Microsoft-Edge from C# code (Process.exit()). Edge save all the tabs that were open in a recovery files located in:

```
C:\Users\<myusername>\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\AC\MicrosoftEdge\User\Default\Recovery\Active
```

When I manually delete them I can see that Edge is loading without the tabs that where open.
Is there some king of flag for the Edge exe for deleting those recovery files?
Of a better way to launch it without the "old" tabs?

I did find a workaround:
After I closing the process I launch it again and close it. the next time edge is loading it will be without the tabs/ recovery files. but it does make edge to flicker (Off/On/Off) which bad UX :\ . That way I'm looking for a better way to do so.